# CBLLiveQuery vs kCBLDocumentChangeNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, key-value-observing, couchbase-lite

Currently I am working on `Couchbase Lite`, and displaying each document in `UITableView`.

My questions is, if a **document_id : abc12345** is updated on server side *(CouchDB) (either manually or from any other app iOS/Android/Web)*, which is better approach to update the **document _id : abc12345** in `UITableView`.

In present situation I am using `CBLLiveQuery`, and I am not happy with it, because it needs a CBLView *(map/reduced function, and I am indexing it based on `_rev` of `CBLDocument`)*, and creating `CBLQuery` and then invoking livequery `[livequery start];` and then observing with KVO and then blah blah blah...

`self.liveQuery = [self startLiveQueryViewWithDatabase:database];
 [self.liveQuery addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rows" options:0 context:NULL];
 [self.liveQuery start];`

The fact which I observed is that whenever the live query instance is invoked **for first time** the KVO method `-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context` gets called without any change in CBLDocument on server.

When any Document on server updated the `-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:` will not give me what has been changed/which document has changed `_id`, It just gives me a bunch of Document Ids `_id`.

When I learned about `kCBLDocumentChangeNotification` it gives me the correct Document ID `_id` which has been updated.

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kCBLDocumentChangeNotification object:self queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        CBLDatabaseChange* changes = note.userInfo[@"change"];
        NSLog(@"Document : [%@]",changes.documentID);
        [self updateUserInterface:changes];
    }];`

please I need to know which concept is better to implement either of these, which one will take less time(if possible technically).

Answer (score 2):

A Query is the action of looking up results from a view's index. Now, a view can index anything in database. It, along with query, could be retrieving all documents, a set of documents, bunch of properties or single property from document(s) or some values that are computed based on properties in document(s).

And, liveQuery is a mechanism to observe updates to these indexes of a view, i.e, notifies changes of view's emit block.

A `kCBLDocumentChangeNotification` simply notifies the change that has happened to the particular document, i.e, a new revision is notified.

```
/** This notification is posted by a CBLDocument in response to a change, i.e. a new revision.
    The notification's userInfo contains a "change" property whose value is a CBLDatabaseChange
    containing details of the change.
    NOTE: This is *not* a way to detect changes to all documents. Only already-existing CBLDocument
    objects will post this notification, so when a document changes in the database but there is
    not currently any CBLDocument instance representing it, no notification will be posted.
    If you want to observe all document changes in a database, use kCBLDatabaseChangeNotification.*/
extern NSString* const kCBLDocumentChangeNotification;
```

So,
- use `liveQuery` to receive updates for your query.
- use `kCBLDocumentChangeNotification` for updates from a document.
- use `kCBLDatabaseChangeNotification` for updates of all documents.

Comment: Thanks, In `liveQuery` the KVO simply calls the `-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context` even without any change in document on server. which unnecessary pushes a method in stack. whereas  `kCBLDocumentChangeNotification` does not makes unnecessary calls to methods. I know `kCBLDocumentChangeNotification` is slower than `liveQuery` but the delay is negligible. Any further clarification would be appritiated.

Comment: As I said, In liveQuery, you are observing 'rows' and you will be notified every time it has a new value.